# how to move an inside container beyond its outside container?

Tags: css

**Edit 1**

Have updated with a jsfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/DrFSV/

See the wavy image in the last row? I'm trying to get that move outside of #outer_middle.

Advice?

This pertains to the original link. Have removed site's link.

I have a div container named #outer_middle, and inside that, I have two other containers named #middle and #sidebar.

I am trying to have a div inside #middle go a bit outside the container ...

So, I put position:relative to #outer_middle, and position:absolute to #diy (the one with black border) coupled with left:-90px;

(as per my understanding that if you're trying to get an inside container move outside of its outside container, you need to put relative and absolute positioning like this).

It affects the sidebar (pink column) and that goes underneath #middle and the diy image goes to the left *inside the container*, not outside.

Why?

How can I get the #diy move to the left outside of the container?

And is it possible to do this so #diy remains in the flow as well?

Advice, please? Please let me know if my question is unclear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `#outer_top` and `#top` to the code below. See if that's what you are trying to achieve:

```
#outer_top {
  background-color: red;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#top {
  margin: 0 0 0 -90px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: um ... i'm not trying to adjust my #outer_top and #top. i'm trying to move #diy outside of the container #middle.

Comment: i know but i just want to see if that's what you trying to achieve. I tried to change the one you want, but seems like your CSS a bit messy..

Comment: hey zen, tried your answer for the #top ... it seems to work. but when i tried to apply to #diy, it still moves to the left inside the container. the upside of your answer is that somehow the right sidebar (pink column) seems to have come back to its position. hm.

Comment: ok..then try to do this now

    #outer_middle {
      width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: white;
      position: relative;
      height: 400px;
    }

    #outer_sidebar {
      background-color: pink;
      height: 400px;
      width: 300px;
      margin: 0 0 0 -30px;
    }

Then try to remove your `#middle` div at all..see if that works.

Comment: zen, i looked at your css code ... the problem is that #middle is holding 4 of my divs, include #diy. plus, it moves the sidebar which is not what i needed here. but thank you very much for trying to help.

Comment: In your jsfiddle:
1. Remove `overflow` in `#outer_box`
2. Add `margin: 0 0 0 -30px;` in `#classes`

Comment: zen! it worked! i tried it in jsfiddle. then i tried it on my site. it works! it works! (your jsfiddle code, i mean). but i keep thinking i need overflow. can't remember why i put it in the first place. it was in reaction to something, and overflow fixed it somehow. kind of worried that it'll do something else now. hm.

Comment: That's why I asked you to remove your `#middle` before. I suspect you put wrong codes in there..that `overflow` is not necessary to be there I believe. You'll need it if you have `float` but otherwise, you can remove it.

Comment: oh darn! just realized that my jsfiddle code doesn't have float. but my site does. and i need it!

Comment: update your jsfiddle code, and then I'll have a look at it again.

Comment: what if you use `min-height: 780px;` in your `#middle`, instead of `overflow`. Does that solve the problem?

Comment: hey @zen, sorry for taking so long on getting back. had to go somewhere. anyway, looked at my jsfiddle again, and it does have the float properties applied to it. and your code still worked with it, albeit with a removal of overflow. and i checked a bit on my site again right now, and it seems to work, so, i'm happy about it. can you just tell me why i need overflow for float though? otherwise, thank you so much for your time and help. it's really really appreciated.

Comment: no worries mate. I'm glad it works. You need `overflow` because when you create a div with `float` in it. The parent div will collapse, unless you specify `height` or `min-height` for the parent div. But if you put `overflow` the parent div will get the height of the inner div as it's own height. The side effect from `overflow` is that your parent div creates clipping region. Whatever doesn't fit inside that parent div will be cut off. Hopefully it's clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it seems like your `#diy` element is already to the left of the container, it's just not "outside", as you put it.

Try adjusting the `z-index` CSS property of the #diy element. Elements with greater z-index are placed "higher up" on the page than elements with a lower z-index. To be sure `#diy` is going to be on top, add a z-index of 99:

```
z-index: 99;
```

To the CSS.

Comment: tried that already yesterday. didn't work. did it again right now in case i missed something. look at link, and you can see even with z-index, it still doesn't work. (should have mentioned this in my original post, sorry).

Comment: Well I'll tell you what would be helpful. Replicate the simplest version of your problem on jsfiddle.net, and then link it here so people can mess around with the code themselves and have a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve (that is, if no one can provide an answer that works before you get frustrated enough to take my advice).

Comment: is the link really that complicated? i deliberately left it simple as possible, since i was trying to only deal with #diy to move outside of its container.

Comment: It's not so much that it is complicated, it's just that jsfiddle allows people to mess around with your CSS themselves instead of giving you suggestions and waiting for your feedback. It is much quicker for us, even though it is a bit of a pain for you.

Comment: have updated my post with a jsfiddle link. You're right, it is easier for others, even though it is a huge pain for me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if if you set the overflow for the #outer_middle to visible (or, just remove it) you would get the result you want.

Comment: i put overflow for a reason, admittedly, one i can't remember. wondering how it'll affect it once it's removed. (it's removed btw, right now). i think it was because i was having trouble with the inner divs inside #middle.